# Create Overlays with the New Modal Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, winter23

I am trying to implement the new modal feature in LWC came up with winter 23 release. The link can be found here:- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_modal.htm&type=5&release=240

### myModal.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>This is the modal’s contents.</lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="OK" onclick={handleOkay}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

### myModal.js

```
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {

    handleOkay() {
        this.close('okay');
    }
}
```

### myModal.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

### Issue

The issue is when I try to deploy, it throws the error :-

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH  ERRORS                                     
────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────
              No MODULE named lightning:modalFooter found

11:43:24.180 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

I am trying to deploy pre-release org where winter23 is available.

### Question

Is there anything i am missing with LightningModal in Lightning Web Component?

### Update

I have changed the api version in sfdx package json as well, but it is still throwing error.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "winter23Scenarios",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "56.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modal component even though documented in release notes is not available until the next week (Oct 7th)!!

The PR for this is pending and will be released once all the orgs are on the latest release!!

Comment: Thank you @mohith ,I will wait for this. Looks like a cool feature to me.